# Is it possible to create a new folder in Windows 10 with current date?

Tags: windows-10

Right clicking and creating a new folder creates "New Folder" is it possible to change it? This solution is for 7 and does not work with 10 > [Link](https://superuser.com/questions/520031/how-to-change-new-folder-default-name-for-folders-in-explorer-to-current-date).

I wanted something like 2018-08-16.

Comment: it should work. The `DATE` variable is always there in any Windows versions. But it's locale dependent so you need to change the date format, or better use the [locale indepent way](https://superuser.com/q/1287756/241386)

Comment: It does not work with 10 anymore.

Comment: See if this works.....https://advsurveying.com/creating-a-new-folder-in-win-7-using-as-the-name/